# Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this errors when I run my code. How can I change the user `www-data` to `root`?

//Errors recorded in Terminal

```
[Tue Mar 03 10:33:01.023877 2015] [:error] [pid 3161] [client 127.0.0.1:37725] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/html/wow/register.php on line 23, referer: http://localhost/wow/register.php

[Tue Mar 03 10:33:01.023957 2015] [:error] [pid 3161] [client 127.0.0.1:37725] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/html/wow/register.php on line 23, referer: http://localhost/wow/register.php


// Codes inside register.php
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Perform the verification of the nation
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $confirmEmail = $_POST['confirmEmail'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      $confirmPass = $_POST['confirmPass'];

        if($email == $confirmEmail){
            if($pass == $confirmPass){
                //All good, Carry on.
                  $firstName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
                  $lastName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
                  $userName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
                  $email = mysql_escape_string('email');
                  $confirmEmail = mysql_escape_string('confirmEmail');
                  $pass = mysql_escape_string('pass');
                  $confirmPass = mysql_escape_string('confirmPass');

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `userName`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstName', '$lastName', '$userName', '$email', '$pass')") or die("Can't Connect!");


            } else{
                echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match. <br />";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, your email's do not match. <br />";
        }
} else{

    $form = <<<EOT
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br />
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br />
            Username: <input type="text" name="userName"/><br />
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
            Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="confirmEmail"/><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/><br />
            Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPass"/><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
        </form>
EOT;

}

echo $form;

?>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what  your question is. Maybe try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and editing your post to make things clearer.

Comment: please post config.php I am guessing there is where you declare username ans password for database connection

Comment: check your .htaccess file, try to debug after removing it. Take backup of file before you start debuging.

Comment: config.php has this code only Ma'am,

<?php 

?>

Can't move to this part because of the errors above.

Comment: Search www-data in you entire project and let me know if you get any result.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is when you trying to connect to the Database.

On `config.php` you might see something like `www-data` as your database user, change it to the right username and password.

Also you can search the word `www-data` in your project.

You got the second error because the first error. Since your connection failed your link is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL username or password is incorrect (it is currently blank) or the user www-data is not allowed to connect on the domain localhost.

You need to create a user in MySQL and assign access and privileges to that database or if already done, check that you put the correct details.

Also, mysql_connect and 'mysql' functions are depreciated now. Upgrade to mysqli.

Some references you can use to get started.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

where is the db?  are you using godaddy hosting?  it seems there are multiple websites affected with this error from yesterday Mar 3rd around 16:10 UTC. (your time matches with this incident) if you are sure the username, p/w or privilege of the user id was not changed, check with the db admin to do some restoration of the id. (PS: my points do not allow comment)